# Flutter: Access Bloc from context inside a static function

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to invoke a bloc event from a static function that takes a context as a parameter. The context derives from the part of the widget tree where BlocProvider is defined.

However, it tells me `context**.read**` isn't defined (probably because the function isn't inside a build method)

My question is, whether or not it's possible to invoke an bloc event like that.

My function:

```html
static void someFunction(BuildContext context) {
  context.read<MyBlock>().add(MyBlocEvent());
}
```

Widget tree:

```html
- Main App
  - App
  - Material App : BlockProvider
    - MyWidget : Calls a static function that isn't inside a Stateless/ful widget
```

Comment: Please show the widget tree in question.

Comment: make sure to import the flutter bloc

Comment: @MD Yeasin Sheikh Here you go